# Why is net.minecraft.entity.Entity.getServer() returning null?

Tags: java, minecraft

I was recently writing a fabric mc minecraft mod for 1.19.1, and I have a single, simple question, that I can't find answer for:
Why is client.player.getServer() returning null, where I'm running it like this:

```
ClientTickEvents.END_CLIENT_TICK.register(client -> {
    client.player.getServer().getPlayerNames()
});
```

The exception I'm getting: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.getPlayerNames()" because the return value of "net.minecraft.client.network.ClientPlayerEntity.getServer()" is null`
Does anyone know what is going on? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was returning null, because the mod was client-sided, and client-sided mods cannot get the MinecraftServer class.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this documentation](https://taylorgoolsby.github.io/forge-javadocs/docs/javadoc-1.15.2/net/minecraft/client/entity/player/ClientPlayerEntity.html) it inherits [this method](https://taylorgoolsby.github.io/forge-javadocs/docs/javadoc-1.15.2/net/minecraft/entity/Entity.html#getServer--), which is the `#getServer()` method.

According to the documentations, the return value is `@Nullable`.

In other words, you would most likely want to check if the method returns `null` before doing anything with it.

The most convincing answer that came to my mind is that the player isn't in a server at all.

In other words, player is in a local world hence it doesn't return a `MinecraftServer`.

Comment: But actually in minecraft even if you are playing singleplayer, you are just starting internal server, that only you can join, so I think it's not the case, and I also tested it in multiplayer, and game crashes then too, but anyways thanks for the answer! :D

Comment: @BlayUng We must be playing in different worlds then :) Anywho, please consider my suggestion to check if the return value is null first so that you won't just blow your foot off in the middle of processing data.

Comment: @BlayUng you are correct, that is how the game was changed to support single player about 8 years ago. I'd be more curious as to what conditions `#getServer()` returned null, e.g. if it was mid-logout or in the main menu.

Comment: @Rogue, I searched up the code of the game, and I noiticed such comment above the getServer() function of the Entity class: `{@return the server the entity is in, or {@code null} if called on the client side}`. This is probably why it returned null (I was writing a client-sided mod) Besides, that function was returning this.world.getServer(), so I went to the declaration of the world.getServer() function, and it was simply returning null every time you called it, altough it had @Override, so this is why this function could ever be useful (it's probably changed somewhere else in the code).

Comment: Indeed, those changed quite a bit with the world-gen implementation changes. You're likely looking at one of the base classes.